# Select2 deselect all values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selection, jquery-select2

I want to deselect all values with one click without using each `id` seperately.

I fiddled around for a while, but this deselect only first value. Any suggestions?

This is how I try to deselect:

```
$( "#mybutton" ).click(function() {    
   $("select").select2('val', '')
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6hZFU/75/

Comment: Please add code to a question that contains a fiddle.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$('select').select2({
    placeholder: "select me"
});

$("#mybutton").click(function () {
    $("select").each(function () { //added a each loop here
        $(this).select2('val', '')
    });
});
```

**Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/CsBfE/)**

Comment: @danip, what version of select2 are you using, bunch of changes with 4.0, added a new answer below

Comment: @Steve yes, I had problems with 4.0 but I still don't get why the each syntax works and multiple selector doesn't

Answer (score 73):

```
$("select").val('').change();
```

That is all :)
http://jsfiddle.net/6hZFU/78/

Explanation: when you change value of any input or select through JavaScript browser will not fire change event for that change (that is how specs say).

When you fire change event select2 will catch up and reflect new value of select.

Comment: Yes, because when you change value of any input or select through JavaScript browser will not fire change event for that change. When you fire change event select2 will catch up and reflect new value of select.

Comment: Your last comment should be added to your answer for clarification.  Good explanation.

Answer (score 21):

If using Select2 version 4.0, you will need to use the new syntax:

```
$("select").val(null).trigger("change");
```

Comment: Works for Version: 3.4.5   Thanks :)

Comment: This does not work on version 4, you have to enter empty string inside the `val` function. `.val('')`.

Answer (score 8):

In case someone is interested in the Select2 native configuration solution (**no separate button**).

As of time of writing (select2 v 4), Select2 can add a button to clear multiselection. No need for `<option></option>` workaround for placeholder to appear:

```
$('#my-select').select2({
    placeholder: "Select something",
    allowClear: true
});
```

From [the documentation](https://select2.org/selections#clearable-selections).

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#destinatariMail').val("-1").trigger("change");
```

This way you will deselect also tagged options that have been inserted "on-the-fly".

Answer (score 2):

I tried the above solutions but it didn't work for me.

This is kind of hack, where you do not have to `trigger change.`

```
$("select").select2('destroy').val("").select2();
```

or

```
$("select").each(function () { //added a each loop here
        $(this).select2('destroy').val("").select2();
});
```

Comment: Exactly what I need! Thanks dude.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to clear multiple multiselect dropdown using Select2 v4 api, here is a simple way:

```
$("li.select2-selection__choice").remove();
$(".select2").each(function() { $(this).val([]); });
```

No focus on dropdown and clean both "select" and "Select2" elements ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need use the class of your select(*select2_single*)

Example:

```
$('#button_clear').click(function () 
{
    $('.select2_single').select2('val',''); 
});
```

---

Debes usar la clase de tus select

Ej:

```
$('#button_clear').click(function () 
{
    $('.select2_single').select2('val',''); 
});
```

Comment: Please post answers in english. Thank you

Comment: Could you provide your answer in english. Thanks

Comment: Ok, no problem, sorry for this problem!

Comment: Ok robert, i try provide answers in inglish!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it's working perfectly.

```
$('#form-search-amenities > option').prop("selected", false);
$("li.select2-selection__choice").remove();
```

`#form-search-amenities` should e replace by ID of your `<select>` dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('#mySelect2').val('');
$('#mySelect2').trigger('change.select2');
```